# Second menu has the first menu ID

Tags: theme-development, menus, headers, twitter-bootstrap

I registered two menus top-menu and main-menu.

I created two menu on the admin panel and assigned one to each (different items)

But when I view the front end, I see that the two menus have the same items, and the main menu has an id "menu-top-menu-1"

Here is what I have:

functions.php

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus (array(
        'main-menu' => 'Main Menu',
        'top-menu' => 'Top Menu',
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

header.php

Top menu:

```
 <div class=" top-menu-container">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'container' => 'nav',
            'container_class' => 'container',
            'item_location' => 'top-menu',
            'menu_class' => 'nav top-menu pull-right',
        )); 
        ?>
 </div>
```

Main menu:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="logo col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img class="block-center " src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"/></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wrap" id="main-menu-toggle">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'item_location' => 'main-menu', 
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse nav-wrap',
            'container_id' => 'main-menu-toggle',
            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav main-menu',
        )); 
        ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

Here is the rendered output of both Top menu and Main menu

```
<nav class="container">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="nav top-menu pull-right">
        <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4"><a href="#">CanHerp</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5"><a href="#">Rescues</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#">Breeders</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wrap" id="main-menu-toggle">
  <div id="main-menu-toggle" class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wrap">
    <ul id="menu-top-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav main-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4"><a href="#">CanHerp</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5"><a href="#">Rescues</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#">Breeders</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I'd also like to know if that's the best way to deal with bootstrap responsive menu (for the main menu'.

Comment: Pretty sure `item_location` should not be `top-men`.

Comment: I corrected the typo, still doesn't work the way it should. I'd like to know what is wrong

Comment: "I'd like to know what is wrong" -- I'd tell you if I knew.

Comment: The parameter you're looking for is `theme_location`, not `item_location`.

Comment: Oh, you saved me, I never realized where the error was. Thank you. Would you please add the answer to mark it as the best one?

Comment: No problem -- I'm glad it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comments: The parameter you're looking for is `theme_location`, not `item_location`.

Answer (score 1):

Register your menu like this...

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary1'   => __( 'Top primary menu First', 'ank' ),
        'primary2'   => __( 'Top primary menu Second', 'ank' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary menu in left sidebar', 'ank' ),
    ) );
```

and Use in code like this...

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary2' ) ); ?>
```

use theme_location instant-of item_location ......

Comment: I am aware of the __() function to make the word ready for translation, I don't need it in this specific theme, that's why. Thank you for your answer as well.